# How can I pass a list of values as a parameter for a TOraQuery?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a TOraQuery with SQL defined something like this

```
SELECT ML.ID, Ml.detail1, Ml.detail2
FROM MY_LIST ML 
WHERE 
    ML.ID in (:My_IDS)
```

If I was to build this query on the fly, I'd naturally end  up with something like this:

```
SELECT ML.ID, Ml.detail1, Ml.detail2
FROM MY_LIST ML 
WHERE 
    ML.ID in (14001,14002,14003)
```

However, I'd like to pass in `14001,14002,14003` as a parameter.

```
  myListQuery.Active := False;
  myListQuery.ParamByName('My_IDS').AsString := '14001,14002,14003';
  myListQuery.Active := True;
```

But of course that generates an `ORA-01722: invalid number`. Do I have any other option other than building up the query on the fly.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: 11g, but I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Comment: Oracle side: function returning `sys_refcursor` with input parameter `table of` can help. Unfortunately I have no installed Oracle for now so I can not provide whole solution.

Comment: Just add "Oracle" tag to your question and you will get more detailed answer.

Comment: I don't think the Oracle tag is germane to the question. It's not that it is a problem with Oracle. It's that the DevArt ODAC TOraQuery component is IMHO incomplete (functionality wise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Macro"

Not quite what I was looking for, but it's a hair closer to a parameter than building the SQL on the fly.

Create the TOraQuery like this

```
SELECT ML.ID, Ml.detail1, Ml.detail2
FROM MY_LIST ML 
WHERE 
    ML.ID in (&My_IDS)
```

Now I can pass in `14001,14002,14003` as a macro.

```
myListQuery.Active := False;
myListQuery.MacroByName('My_IDS').value := '14001,14002,14003';
myListQuery.Active := True;
```

Comment: Main reason why is do not use mutable queries is the optimization module of the Oracle. With Oracle it can be 90% of the time to spent for query execution. Keep it in mind.

Comment: Understood... along with tendencies for SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible directly.

You'll have to convert the list into a SQL list in plain text.

For instance:

```
function ListToText(const Args: array of string): string; overload;
var 
  i: integer;
begin
  result := '(';
  for i := 0 to high(Args) do 
    result := result+QuotedStr(Args[i])+',';
  result[length(result)] := ')';
end;


function ListToText(const Args: array of integer): string; overload;
var 
  i: integer;
begin
  result := '(';
  for i := 0 to high(Args) do 
    result := result+IntToStr(Args[i])+',';
  result[length(result)] := ')';
end;
```

To be used as such:

```
SQL.Text := 'select * from myTable where intKey in '+ListToText([1,2,3]);
SQL.Text := 'select * from myTable where stringKey in '+ListToText(['a','b','c']);
```

Or in your case:

```
myListQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT ML.ID, Ml.detail1, Ml.detail);
myListQuery.SQL.Add('FROM MY_LIST ML ');
myListQuery.SQL.Add('WHERE ');
myListQuery.SQL.Add('ML.ID in ') +  ListToText([14001,14002,14003]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but it requires some additional setup. Hopefully this works with your version of Oracle.

1. Create a table type
2. Create a function that converts your string to your table type
3. Use CAST in the subquery. Pass your value to the bind variable using the same thing you have in your code (i.e. ParamByName('').AsString).

   ```
   create or replace type myTableType as table of varchar2 (255);

   create or replace function in_list( p_string in varchar2 ) return myTableType as 
       l_string        long default p_string || ',';
       l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
       n               number;
   begin
     loop
         exit when l_string is null;
         n := instr( l_string, ',' );
         l_data.extend;
         l_data(l_data.count) := 
                ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
         l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
     end loop;

   return l_data;
   end;

   select * from THE ( select cast( in_list(:MY_BIND_VARIABLE) as mytableType ) from dual ) a
   ```

If this works for you, credit for the answer and example code goes to Tom Kyte from Oracle who runs asktom.com. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425